# changing width of button in navigation bar CSS

Tags: html, css

So my html is this:

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my CSS is this:

```
#background {
    min-widh: 960px;
}

#navigation {
    min-width: 960px;
} 

#navigation ul {
    min-width: 960px;
} 

#navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now, this does create an inline bar except no matter how much I change the width and height of

```
#navigation ul li
```

the background color (red) just stays strictly around the letters and nothing else. It seems as if the width and heights of the actual li's are not changing no matter what number I change it to. Any idea why it is doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead or `display:inline`.

```
#navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vj2Fy/)

Alternatively, you can also float the elements for a similar effect:

```
#navigation ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vj2Fy/1/)

Aside from both of the above solutions, if you wanted to use `display:inline`, you could just add padding as opposed to trying to set a height/width.

```
#navigation ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding:20px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vj2Fy/2/)

Comment: Ah, perfect. And how come just display: inline doesn't work? Why does making it inline-block work? Also, why does making it float left also work?

Comment: "This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box." http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display